# Why won't CSS won't work on specific situation

Tags: css, laravel

So I'm working a project of a Website. In it, there's an admin page where I can add or remove images that will be shown on the website. I created a Controller for the Main Admin page alone, and then I created a controller for every type of information that can be changed through that page (Porfolio, banner, etc). All the pages are styled by CSS. So when my AdmController returns the view with the main Admin page, everything works fine

The adress for the main Admin Page results in **localhost:8000/adm**

But once I try to open a view where I would add an image to be shown on the Main page, CSS simply won't work. To acess, say, the add banner page, I have a BannerController that will return a "form-banner" view, resulting in the adress **localhost:8000/adm/banner**. In this page CSS does not work.

I wanted to test further so I created a new Route that would take me directly to the create banner page without going through the admin page, and also not using any Controllers at all. I got the adress **localhost:8000/banner**. Now CSS works.

Any ideas why?

These are the routes including the one I created just to test the view:

```
Route::resource('adm', 'AdmController');

Route::resource('adm/banner', 'BannerController');

Route::get('banner', function () {
    return view('admin/form-banner');
});
```

This is the AdmController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdmController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin/index');
    }
}
```

This is how the BannerController is returning the mal-functioning View:

```
    public function create()
    {
        return view('admin/form-banner')
```

And this is the point in the Main Adm View (the one that works) where It calls the BannerController:

```
<ul class="nav-second-level" aria-expanded="false">
    <li><a href="adm/banner/create">Create new banner</a></li>
```

Comment: please share your code for better understanding.

Comment: Added all the parts of the code that I mentioned, sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your CSS like below

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

the absolute path after your public folder